# Azure Maps - Unable to set layer options 'offset' from point properties without browser warnings

Tags: azure-maps

I'm trying to use the offset parameters for the text label in relation to the position of the point (marker) on the map.

In my app, the user sets their preference to the x & y-axis offset values, which when changed, update the map point properties. I then need to use data-driven expressions to pull the values from each map point properties when updating the point layer options.

[image]

[image]

When the point is first created, the offset property of the point is set as below:

```
offset: [0, 0],
```

When updating the point layer, I've tried using the expression formulas below, but none of them are working without getting warnings in the browser debug console.

```
layers.pointLayer.setOptions({
    iconOptions: {
        offset: [ // ******NEEDS FIXING*******
            'case', // Use a conditional case expression.

            ['has', 'offset'],   // Check to see if feature has an "offset" property
            //["length", ["array", ["get", "offset"]]] // not working
            ['get', 'offset'],   // not working without browser warning
            //['get', ['literal', [0, 0]]], // not working
            //['literal', [0,0]], // working but not relevant, set locally, not pulling value from properties!!!

            'literal', [0, 0]]  // If it doesn't, default to array [0,0] (x & y-axis).
        ]
    }
})
```

If using the example ['get', 'offset'], in the expression, although I can actually modify the offset and it works on the map as shown in the screenshot, I get the following warning in the browser debug console:

[image]

I'd like to have a warning free environment as any debug warnings. I obviously need to get the formatting set correctly in the data driven expression when setting the options for the layer (2nd code sample) but none of the syntax I've tried so far are working correctly.

I also tried studying the MS example [here](https://codepen.io/azuremaps/pen/PxVXje), but it seems they don't actually pull the offset values from the map point properties, they are setting the layer options directly from the user form which is no good unless i wanted to implement a global change for all points that belong to this particular layer.

Comment: Can you clarify the example that has given the error you added in the image? "Expected value to be of type array" . And if you have an example for testing can you share so I try to repro? Thanks

Comment: Hi, I gave up using expressions in the end and went down a different route completely.

Comment: Can you share the solution as an answer?

Comment: Hi, I would be concerend about getting marked down by someone for posting an answer thats not relevant to the queston being asked.

Comment: Sure. Please leverage https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/topics/25319/azure-maps.html as needed.